# WillCascadeOnDelete not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two tables

```
public class ServiceRendering
{
  [DataMember]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public virtual IList<ServiceRenderingProduct> ServiceRenderingProducts { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceRenderingProduct
{
  [ForeignKey("ServiceRendering")]
  [DataMember]
  public int ServiceRenderingId { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public virtual ServiceRendering ServiceRendering { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And set relation between them

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceRendering>().HasMany(x => x.ServiceRenderingProducts).WithRequired(x => x.ServiceRendering).HasForeignKey(x => x.ServiceRenderingId  ).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But on deleting ServiceRenderingEntity, I don't get deleting of ServiceRenderingProduct entities. Should I set any constraints in database? Or is there another reason?

Comment: Hmm, I try your code and ServiceRenderingProduct deletes after deleting ServiceRendering

Comment: It's really strange. What version of EF do you use?

Comment: Maybe TransactionScope could affect on deleting.

Comment: In EF generated database, ServiceRendering FK contains cascade delete rule?

Comment: Yes, there is such key in EF generated database. But I haven't it in my own base. Should I have it, or relation in modelbuilder is enough?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now. Did you find out how to solve it?

Comment: @BrunoSantos, yes. You should to have constrains on your tables. Attributes in code isn't enough.